# VueJS DataTables fixedHeader not working

Tags: datatables, vue.js, fixed-header-tables

Any one please suggest me how to make fixedHeader property working in vue.js with dataTables

```js
vm.$nextTick(function() {
  currentTable.DataTable({
    "language": {
      "search": "Free Text Filter:"
    },
    fixedHeader: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In the future, [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46783646/edit) the question rather than adding code in comments.

Comment: have you tried using the constructor? https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not include css/js file for fixedHeader in your code. please include the link `https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.css` in head section of your page and this `https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js` in your script section. It may solve your problem.